# Connecting to Web Service in VM from client in host

Tags: web-services, ubuntu, port, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 in VirtualBox with Windows 7 as host. I have a java Web Service which I deploy onto a Glassfish3 server in Ubuntu and I want to be able to reach it from the host, according to the VBox documentation I should port forward port 8080 which is the port that my client application connects to on my host. To do this I do the following command in Windows `VBoxManage modifyvm Ubuntu --natpf1 glassfish,tcp,,8080,,8080` which should forward my hosts 8080 port to my VM's 8080 port, but it doesn't seem to work when I try to reach it. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you can reach the VM from the host? I mean ping it or something.

Comment: How would I manage to ping it? the IP is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure 8080 is not already used by some other process in Windows. Install Guest Additions from the ISO inside Ubuntu. Ensure you are using NAT as the option for networking. Ensure the firewall in Ubuntu does not block incoming requests.

Comment: No process on the port, Guest Additions is installed and NAT is my networking option. How can i check the firewall permissions?

Comment: You can install Firestarter as your firewall and see if Ubuntu's IPtables is blocking any requests in real time. However, I feel that if you have GUist Additions and NAT working, then there should be no problem. Check if the VboxManage syntax is correct. You double check that the web service is running on 8080 in the VM. After that, you should type http://[IP_Address_Of_VM_On_VirtualBox_Subnet:8080/ inside a browser. That you can use localhost and export port forwarding to happen properly.